# Why golang garbage-collector not implement Generational and Compact gc?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Generational and Compact gc have already been thought best practice. But golang doesn't adopt it. Who can tell me the reason?

Comment: Did you ever implement a compacting GC? Any idea how complicated compactification is?

Comment: @Volker I'm not an expert on gc. But many people  and golang author are. Do you mean it is too difficult to implement for golang expert? Or there are other considerations.

Comment: Yes. too complicated to get right (correct and low latency).

Comment: Don't know why you're getting downvoted (I upvoted you); this is a perfectly reasonable question to ask. I know this has been explained somewhere in the past, but I forget the details. Go's GC is not generational because the generational hypothesis is less-true for Go (which allocates much on the stack or in continguous blocks) than for pointer-based languages. Not sure about the 'compacting' part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a GC expert, but here are a few links that seem to explain the desig:

https://blog.golang.org/go15gc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiv1JOfMjm0

https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/17503-eliminate-rescan.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Here is the patient and enlightening reply from golang-nuts.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/KJiyv2mV2pU